# Mandar imagem para impressão automaticamente a partir de app web (html, js e php)

Tags: javascript, php, java, html, impressão

Olá, tenho um webapp onde eu tiro uma foto com uma moldura para um crachá e salvo ela no servidor, porém precisava mandar essa imagem imprimir automaticamente, ignorando aquele prompt que surge quando mandamos imprimir algo no navegador por exemplo.

Tentei um software em java, fiz o programa que mandava imprimir em java, mas quando chamava a sua execução através do exec() do php ele não enxerga nenhum serviço de impressão, fiz uma pergunta sobre este caso aqui já, mas não consegui solução.

Isso irá rodar em duas máquinas, mas cada uma terá um servidor local instalado, e rodará num ambiente controlado. Então poderá ser alguma "gabiarra" mesmo, mas como não ter aquele prompt é um requisito do sistema, preciso de algum caminho que faça isso funcionar.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

o php tem uma biblioteca pra fazer isso 
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.printer.php

Uso

```
<?php
$texto = "Conteúdo a ser impresso";
$_SESSION['PrintBuffer']="$texto"; 
$handle=printer_open("nome_da_impressora_no_windows");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
printer_write($handle, $_SESSION['PrintBuffer']);
printer_close($handle);
?>
```

Eu não efetuei o teste por estar sem impressora aqui, mas creio que você vai conseguir a impressão direta sem passar por um prompt.